# PHP strlen function not working properly

Tags: php

Following is my PHP Code:

```
echo "With Duplicate Values: ".sizeof($filteredNumbers);
$sortedNumbers = array_unique($filteredNumbers);
echo "<br />Without Duplicate Values: ".sizeof($sortedNumbers);
// print_r($sortedNumbers);

$validNumbers = $invalidNumbers = array();

foreach ($sortedNumbers as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        if(strlen($value1) == 10)
            {
                $validNumbers[] = $value1;
            }

        else
            {
                $invalidNumbers[] = $value1;
            }
    }
```

I am having an array of 900 numbers, the numbers should be only 10 in length so i ran the above code to check whether if there is any number present which is greater than 10 or less 10 so that I can eliminate it. Although it stores all the invalid numbers in another array it is also storing some around 100 numbers which have a perfect length of 10. Why so? Is there anything with a memory problem or what?

Comment: Whitespace? Maybe use `trim()`

Comment: var_dump($numbers) to check exact length.

Comment: Is $sortedNumbers associative array?

Comment: @kerbholz yes it has white spaces but i used trim also it is trimming for some values and not for some values

Comment: @Smartpal its showing 11 also i ran trim but some values get trimmed some do not

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL nopes

Comment: It would be better if you could somehow share the array with few numbers of length 10 but not coming as valid along with few numbers with length 10(comin valid) and few numbers with length not 10.

Comment: Regular expression may help to filter your data

Comment: @kerbholz & @Smartpal there was whitespaces problem so i updated my code to this `$newval = trim($value2);
               if(strlen($newval) == 10)` and that solved the problem.